# Как объединить две базы: реляционную и графовую?

Tags: php, mysql

Как реализовать данное объединение, на примере mysql и neo4j.

Comment: Данные перенести?

Comment: Это нужно для разработки сайта. Mysql будет использоваться как основная база, а в neo4j будет храниться пользователи и их связь между собой (друзья). 

Возможно ли так сделать?

Comment: В чем проблема все данные в MySQL поместить?

Comment: проблема такова: на сайте будут пользователи и у них есть друзья, у друзей есть друзья и т.д., вложение в 3 уровня. Нужно выводить новости друзей, друзей-друзей и друзей-друзей-друзей. Такое реализовать в Mysql через join'ы будет слишком медленно. Может кто-то знает, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Какое время для запроса в MySQL и на каком размере таблицы Вы получили? 

Что количественно (в секундах) означает **слишком медленно**?

Comment: На данный момент сайт находится в разработке, и стоит вопрос выбора базы данных. Мы рассматривание в несколько миллионов пользователей и нужно хранить сообщения данных пользователей их будет соответственно на много больше. По опыту работы с mysql, я думаю что он не потянет, такое количество запросов.

Comment: Подход понятен.

Comment: Может, кто знает другую базу данных, которая подойдет лучше?